# Pandas: "Zip-like" selection

Tags: python, pandas

Currently, when using the lookup method on a df one obtains zip-like selection, e.g.

```
df.lookup(["one","two"],["a","b"])
```

will select two values: one with rowlabel "one" and collabel "a" and another with "two" and "b".
Now, when using the method a warning appears that the method will not be available in future versions and that one should use the "loc" method.

I really don't know how to obtain the same "zip-like" behavior with loc. Can anyone explain/help?

Comment: Have you seen the pandas docs on [Looking up values by index/column labels](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup)? Can you make that solution work for your purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following alternatives (equally in result) to deprecated `df.lookup`:

```
[df.loc[p] for p in zip(["one","two"], ["a","b"])]
```

---

```
list(map(df.at.__getitem__, zip(["one","two"], ["a","b"])))
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a good alternative - although I must confess that the lookup method call seems more concise. Really don't understand why this method will not be available in the future.